# Import hexdump into IDA pro

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

Since IDA pro has the Hex dump tab I am carious to know is there any way to import hex dump into IDA pro and watch its assembly instructions?

Comment: Is it a textual hex-dump?

Answer (score 1):

Import your hexdump as binary, and press "C" to force the disassembler to process your instructions.

[image]

Comment: I Import it into IDA pro but I can not see the instructions. When I press the c it did not do any thing.. Also for you pic when you click right it show code for c to you but for me c is a analyze selected area. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found it. But it need to select each part separately and then press c. Is there any way that can process all of instructions at one time! since my file is too big

Comment: IDA scripting should help you for that task : https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/201.shtml